# iOS + FMDatabase: DB opens, but can't be queried

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I'm using [FMDatabase](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (subclassed to be a singleton) as a wrapper for an SQLite3 database. I am trying to write a feature in my app that updates the database over the air if necessary. After the update I set `databaseSingleton = nil`, and then call the accessor again to create a new singleton with the new DB. For some reason this results in some strange behavior. For example, if I call `[FMDatabase open]` it returns TRUE, but when I try querying it fails `[FMDatabase databaseExists]` and logs that the DB is not open. This essentially means that the database pointer is simultaneously satisfying `if (db)` and `if (!db)`. I've tried logging the object to the console but it throws an access error, which leads me to believe it doesn't actually exist. Can anyone think of what could be doing this? Or more importantly, how it's even possible for those two conditions to be true?